# matplotlib animation function wants an argument, which is not needed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


def animate(t):

    x = np.random.normal(0,1,[1000,1])
    y = np.random.normal(0,1,[1000,10])    



    for i,v in enumerate(range(y.shape[1])):
        op = x
        hop = y[:,[i]]
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(op,hop)



ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Notice function animate() has argument t > animate(t). I really don't understand why, as t doesn't mean anything, it doesn't rely on anything in the code. Why is this necessary? If I create a function with no arguments > animate() and run the code, I get this error:

```
TypeError: animate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I am so confused why this t is needed. It just doesn't make any sense it doesn't pass any information.

Comment: Works fine for me in matplotlib 2.2.2

Comment: @Bazingaa It runs with out passing argument t in animate function?

Comment: Yes, it runs as it is for me in jupyter notebook. I used `from IPython.display import HTML` and then `HTML(ani.to_html5_video())`. A video is generated animating the scatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [`FuncAnimation` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html),

```
FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, ...)
```

> `func` : callable
>   The function to call at each frame. **The first argument will be the next value in `frames`**. Any additional positional arguments can be supplied via the fargs parameter.
>
> [...]
>
> `frames` : iterable, int, generator function, or None, optional
>   Source of data to pass func and each frame of the animation
>
> If an iterable, then simply use the values provided. If the iterable has a length, it will override the save_count kwarg.
>
> If an integer, then equivalent to passing range(frames)
>
> If a generator function, then must have the signature:
>
> ```
>    def gen_function() -> obj
> ```
>
> **If None, then equivalent to passing `itertools.count`**.

(emphasis mine)

So the animating function needs to take an argument, which it generated by whatever `frames` is set to. If `frames = None` as in the case where you don't supply that argument, it will simply be the integer numbers, starting at `0` and counting up until you stop the animation.

To see the argument in action try something like

```
def animate(t):
    print(t)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

or

```
def animate(t):
    print(t)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=[23,56,129], interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

---

Concerning the code in the question, I am not sure what it is supposed to achieve, but I would guess you would rather perform the animation over the columns of `y`.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.random.normal(0,1,[1000,1])
y = np.random.normal(0,1,[1000,10])    

def animate(t):
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(x,y[:,t])

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, you are very correct. Haven't came up with an idea to print(t) within function. Now I understand. I appreciate your help. Thank you.